# How to test if pointer inside an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, preprocessor, bounds

I would like to test if `myCurrentPtr` points inside my array `a`.

`_B` represents the number of values in `a`.
So, `a + _B` shall point the latest value of the array.

```
#define _B ((uint8_t)5)
volatile uint8_t a[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}; //`a` is a pointer to the first array element

if (myCurrentPtr > (a + _B)) {
    printf("Out of bounds!");
}
```

Doesn't compile. Do you have any idea?

Whereas,

```
...
if (myCurrentPtr > (a + 5)) {
    printf("Out of bounds!");
}
```

compiles just fine.

Aren't the two exactly the same after preprocessing?

Comment: What error message?

Comment: Instead of `(a + 5)` use `(a + sizeof(a)*sizeof (<type_of_a>))`.

Comment: Do the C standards guarantee that comparisons applied to pointers are always implicitly and suitably casted?

Comment: "a + _B shall point the latest value of the array." --> No.  `a + _B` points one pass the last.

Comment: Error message: « myfile.c:40:41: warning: (359) illegal conversion between pointer types
pointer to volatile unsigned char -> pointer to unsigned char ». 
Anyway I don't really understand what the compiler expects, since my 2 examples should compile exactly the same.

Comment: Just found out that `if (myCurrentPtr > ( a + ( _B - 1 ) ))` compiles… Weird…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to test if pointer inside an array?

Code can use `>=, >, <, <=` between two object pointers `p,q` is they are in the same array (or just one passed the end of the array). Else code is *undefined behavior*.   C does not have a portable way to test in/outside the array.

The below code is poor

```
if (myCurrentPtr == (a + _B)) {                            // Defined behavior
  printf("pointer just passed a[]\n"); 
} else if (myCurrentPtr >= a && myCurrentPtr < (a + _B)) { // Undefined behavior
  printf("pointer in array\n");        
} else {
  printf("pointer outside array\n");
}
```

Code could explicitly compare one at a time with `==, !=` with `myCurrentPtr` and each element of `a[]`.  Likely this is unsatisfactorily slow, yet reliable.

```
// Dependable, well defined, but slow.
found = false;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
  if (myCurrentPtr == &a[i]) {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Other approaches rely on iffy code.

```
// Iffy code - depending on memory model, may work, may not.
uintptr_t mcp = (uintptr_t) myCurrentPtr;
uintptr_t ia =  (uintptr_t) a;
uintptr_t ia5 = (uintptr_t) &a[5];

if (mcp >= ia && mcp < ia5) {         // Not highly portable
  printf("pointer in array\n");        
} else {
  printf("pointer just passed a[]\n");
}
```

---

The **best approach** to "How to test if pointer inside an array?" is to re-form the problem.  OP did not post *why* this test is needed.  Good code typically can re-work the issue and not use this test.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much for all these illustrated examples! I think I'll re-form the problem as you advise. However I'd also like to know why my example with the #define doesn't compile and learn from this error

Comment: In your 1st example (defined behavior) `if (myCurrentPtr == (a + _B))` raises the error, but `if (myCurrentPtr == (a + 5))`  doesn't

Comment: @TheJeje20 I suspect your 2 codes are not the same in other ways (perhaps difference on type of `myCurrentPtr` or `a`.  Append 2 [MCVE] that demo the error and no error.

Comment: @TheJeje20 Try renaming `_B` to `BBB` and report success or failure.  `_B` is a reserved identifier - you should not define it.  "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore
are always reserved ..."

Comment: I'll post a minimal reproducible example asap :)

Comment: Ok, there was no issue… My IDE is prehistoric! Looks like it needed me to manually refresh its knowledge databases before it launches compilation. *So the two examples are valid and are the same as intended*. Thank you for your help @chux

Comment: @TheJeje20 Setting aside the `_B` issue, I hope you see the 2 codes may _compile_ now, but are not a _valid_ way to "test if pointer inside an array?".

Comment: Of course :) I'll try to re-think this part of my code to avoid being in this situation